# url rewriting with htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my urls in my site so whatever is after the slash is passed as an argument (`example.com/Page` goes to `example.com/index.php?page=Page`)
here is the code that isn't working (it gives a Forbidden):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^/(.+)/$   /index.php?page=$1   [L]
```

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Leave away tha trailing slash (`/`)... And if you want to use that rule inside a `.htaccess` style file, then also leave away the leading one... It might be interesting for you to take a short look at the documentation. It has good examples and would have answered these questions. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html I gave an example below.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I suggested in the comment to your question:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/index\.php
RewriteRule   ^(.+)$   /index.php?page=$1   [L,B]
```

The leading slash does not make sense in `.htaccess` style files, since you do not process an absolute oath in there, but a relative one. About the trailing slash: your example does not show such a slash, so why do you want to have it in the regular expression? It results in your pattern not matching anything but a request terminated by a slash. Which is not what you want.

The `RewriteCond` lines are there to still allow access to physical existing files and directories and to prevent an endless loop, though that should not occur with an internal-only rewriting. And you need the `B` flag to escape the part of the request url you want to specify as `GET` argument.

The last condition is actually obsolete, since obviously `/index.php` should be a file. I leave it in for demonstration purposes.

---

In general it is a very good idea to take a look at the documentation of apaches rewriting module: httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

It is well written, very precise and contains lots of really good examples. It should answer all your questions.

Comment: @Emersont1 You should take a look into your http servers error log file. That is the location where you will find the reason. Without that we can only _guess_ which makes little sense. However my first guess would be: the rewriting module is not available in your http server configuration, you have to load it...

Comment: @Emersont1 Sorry, fixed it. You have to prevent an endless loop in your rewriting.

Comment: well it gives me `/Page/?page=Page`

Comment: I cannot imagine that, sorry. Where should the second slash in this come from? /Page`/`?page=Page

Comment: What error now, 500? Why still? Thought you had another outcome in the mean time?

Comment: Is there an or in the rewrite rule?

Comment: @Emersont1 What "or"? What do you mean? What for?

Comment: so i can go /r/ in the url to stop it from rewriting so i can go `/r/css/style.css`

Comment: @Emersont1 Ah, so unlike in phrased in your question you do _not_ want _every_ request to get rewritten, but only those where no physical files exist. I added two conditions for that too.